# calculate riemann sum of sin to proof limit proposition

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(\frac{k\pi}{n})$$

I'm having trouble expressing $\sin(x)$ differently here in order to calculate the riemann sum.
I want to show that this converges to $\frac{2}{\pi}$ so it equals to $\int_0^1 \sin(x\pi)$.

Is there any easy way to express $\sin(x)$ different here?

**Added:**

$$\frac{1}{2i}(\frac{\cos(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{n})-\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})-1}-\\\frac{\cos(-\frac{(n+1)\pi}{n})+i\sin(-\frac{(n+1)\pi}{n})-\cos(-\frac{\pi}{n})+i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{n})}{\cos(-\frac{\pi}{n})+i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{n})-1})$$

Comment: What's your question exactly? You are already got the right integral.

Comment: Usually, one would calculate your sum by calculating the integral. (The integral is defined in terms of the  limit of Riemann sums.)

Comment: well I got the right integral/limit by trying it out in SAGE. I've not calculated the limit of the expression/the riemann sum by hand.

Comment: @zaiphox: Ok. see the answer. You can have a closed form for your sum and then take the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum can have the closed form

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)= \frac{\sin \left( {\frac {\pi }{n}} \right)}{  \left( 1-\cos \left( {\frac {
\pi }{n}} \right)  \right)} .$$

**Added:** To prove the above identity, you need the two facts

1) $$ \sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}, $$

2) $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}x^m={\frac {{x}^{n+1}-x}{-1+x}}. $$

Comment: Could you explain to me how to deduce the closed form or point me in the right direction via some kind of link?

Comment: @zaiphox: I'll add more hints.

Comment: Could you tell me wether my approach that I added in the OP is right? I'm having trouble getting to the closed formula.

Answer (score 2):

Use that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin kx=\frac{\sin\dfrac{kx}2\sin (k+1)\dfrac x2}{\sin\dfrac{x}2}$$

**ADD** One can deduce the above in several ways. The first is to note it is the imaginary part of $$\sum_{k=0}^n e^{ikx}=\frac{e^{(n+1)ix}-1}{e^{ix}-1}$$

Another choice is to use $$\cos b-\cos a=2\sin\frac{b-a}2\sin\frac{b+a}2$$

Now let $$b=\left(n+\frac 1 2\right)x\\a=\left(n-\frac 1 2\right)x$$

Then you get

$$\cos \left(n+\frac 1 2\right)x-\cos \left(n-\frac 1 2\right)x=2\sin\frac{(n+1)x}2\sin\frac{x}2$$

Then sum and telescope.

Comment: Thanks. Where did you deduce this formula from?

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann sum can be written in closed form by reference to the following trig identity. [List of Trig Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series)

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(k\pi/N)=\cot(\pi/2N)
$$

If you're curious about how *that* can be derived, you will need a bit of cleverness, using the difference of cosine identities.

The Riemann sum is 
$$
(1/N)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(k\pi/N)=(1/N)\cot(\pi/2N)
$$

to take the limit, as $N\rightarrow\infty$, of $\cot(\pi/2N)/N$, write as $\frac{\cos(\pi/2N)}{Nsin(\pi/2N)}=\frac{\cos(\pi/2N)}{sin(\pi/2N)/(1/N)}$  The numerator approaches 1 as $N\rightarrow\infty$ and the denominator approaches $\pi/2$ on account of the well known formula $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}sin(\alpha*x)/x=\alpha$.  Thus the answer is $1/(\pi/2)=2/\pi$ $\square$

### The Trig Identity

As for the trig identity, the strategy is to rewrite each sine as a difference, which can then be used to telescope the series.  If we multiply and divide each term in the series by $\sin(\theta/2)$, the numerator becomes $\sin(k\theta)\sin(\theta/2)$, which can then be written as a difference of cosines.  The series then telescopes so only the first and last term remain.  The conclusion is an exercise in trig identities, which I will omit for now.  I may come back and edit this solution if there are still questions.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.  Nonetheless, the Wiki formula is asserted true for the special case $\theta=\pi/N$, and you seem Ok with this being true in the special case, so I will rewrite the solution accordingly, or did I still misunderstand you.

Comment: The real question, for me, is how to approach this sum if you cannot yet assume $\sin(x)=(\exp{ix}-\exp{-ix} )/ 2\pi$.  Typically, this problem is given in the curriculum before that formula is introduced.  If you know what you're after, the derivation makes sense, but it seems hard to come up with it if you haven't seen "the trick".

Comment: @chappers - thank you for the correction.   I have updated accordingly, but seem to have lost your original comments.

Answer (score 0):

In general,

$\sum_{n=1}^p \sin n\theta=\Im (\sum_{n=1}^p e^{ i n\theta})=\Im (e^{i\theta}\frac{ 1-e^{i p\theta}}{1-e^{i \theta}}),$

which, for $1-e^{i n\theta}=e^{i0}-e^{i n\theta}=e^{i n\theta/2}(e^{-i n\theta/2}-e^{i n\theta/2})= e^{i n\theta/2}\cdot (-2i)\sin(n\theta/2)$, (we can use trigonometric formulas too, which one can notice is essentially the same) equals

$$\Im (e^{i\theta}\frac{ 1-e^{i p\theta}}{1-e^{i \theta}})
=\Im (e^{i\theta}\frac{e^{i p\theta/2}\cdot (-2i)\sin(p\theta/2)}{e^{i \theta/2}\cdot (-2i)\sin(\theta/2}))\\
=\Im (\frac{e^{i (p+1)\theta/2}\sin(p\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)})
=\frac{\sin[(p+1)\theta/2]\sin(p\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}.$$

Therefore,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(\frac{k\pi}{n})
=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\frac{\sin[(n+1)\pi/2n]\sin(n\pi/2n)}{\sin(\pi/2n)}
=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\frac{\cos (\pi/2n)}{\sin(\pi/2n)}=\frac{2}{\pi},$$
for $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.$

This 'proves' $\int_{0}^1 \sin(\pi x) dx=\frac{2}{\pi}.$